# How to save laravel model to 2 databases

Tags: mysql, laravel, replication

Hi is there a way to do something like:

```
$model->name = 'newname'
$model -> save()

Change database connection

$model save()

Change back.
```

I know you can do it with manual queries

```
DB::Conection(conectio1)->update($SQLString)
DB:Coneection(conection2)->update($SQLString)
```

MYSQL replication is not instant
thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way.

```
public function saveMultipleDatabases($db)
{
    Config::set('database.default', $db);

    $model->name = 'newname'
    $model->save()
}
```

Comment: dont know for sure if this affects other users, and they could get conected to other databases:

Answer (score 3):

I have actually never tried that but it should be possible using the [`setConnection()`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setConnection) method of your model.

```php
$model->setConnection('connection2');
```

But you will have to replicate the model before you change anything on the original model instance because otherwise it won't recognise changes of the same attributes with the same values anymore (if they don't differ from the values you used before).

```php
$model2 = $model
    ->replicate()
    ->setConnection('connection2');

$model->name = 'name';
$model->save();

// You need the replicated model here because if you used the same model
// with a different connection the model can not say that `name` has changed
// because the value hasn't changed.
$model2->name = 'name';
$model2->save();
```

Comment: Thank you Dan, I found an easier way

Comment: Could you share your way as an answer so people with the same question can follow that?